# Checking uniqueness of solution to a Laplace equation. Related to minimal surface modelling

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, greens-function, minimal-surfaces

hope you all are doing well.
I am working on minimal surfaces (Chemical engineering background), and I am stuck at a particular problem.
I need to solve Laplace equation with the following boundary conditions

$\frac{\partial^2z}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2z}{\partial y^2} = 0$

boundary conditions: (1) $\frac{\partial z(x, 0)}{\partial y}=C_1$;
(2) $\frac{\partial z(x, 1)}{\partial y}=C_2$;
(3) $\frac{\partial z(0, y)}{\partial x}=0$;
(4) $\frac{\partial z(1, y)}{\partial x}=0$;

I am interested in knowing $\textbf{if a unique solution to this problem exists?}$

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In this case, no, since you can add a constant to any solution and get another one.

Comment: thank you so much Neal, you are a saviour ....